# Is there an unsynchronized java.util.Stack?

Tags: java, stack, standard-library

Is there an unsynchronized version of `java.util.Stack`?

`ArrayList` almost has everything I want, except there doesn't seem to be a method that removes last element in amortized constant time.

I want something that can act like a stack, but still let me have constant random access to the elements.

If there really isn't anything, it isn't a big deal for me to just roll out my own or just use `java.util.Stack`, but it seemed strange to me that I couldn't find `Stack`'s non-synchronized counterpart, that I thought it might be worth asking (also Googling just seemed to point me to other implementations rather than a class in the standard library).

Comment: What does synchronizing have to do with it?

Comment: @Visionstar I have heard it was slower. The docs seem to say we [should 'prefer' ArrayList over Vector unless concurrency is an issue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). But it isn't entirely critical for my purpose; I'm mostly just curious

Comment: I would bet that `arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1)` runs in constant time, even though remove() runs in linear time in the general case.  That's because I suspect the linear time in the general case is used to move all the elements after the removed element up one position in the underlying array.

Answer (score 3):

When the Collections framework was expanded, `Stack` was replaced by the interface [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). It supports the same `push`, `pop`, and `peek` methods of `Stack`.

Implementations of `Deque` include [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Reimeus seems to have suggested `ArrayDeque` too, but I can't seem to be able to find a method for random access in `ArrayDeque`. Also, I would have suspected `LinkedList` would take linear time for retrieving elements

Comment: @math4tots Oh sorry, I missed that part of your question. No, there is no random access in `Deque`. `LinkedList` is linear time as you say (although it's a doubly-linked list, so it can traverse from either end). If you need random access and push/pop methods you will have to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is suggested in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) in the form of a `Deque`

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Comment: does ArrayDeque allow random access?

Comment: Do u mean [this `ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)? Because I don't see any mention of [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) on the page... Although, I would also have imagined that a class named `ArrayDeque` would allow random access... lol

Comment: While `ArrayDeque` organizes its elements by array it doesnt allow random access tho...